# How to add items from a column with the condition refering to another column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm facing some problems when I'm trying to add the content from a column with the condition on another column.

I need something like:
if `user` = x then add the content of column `distance`

Can anybody be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Look into `Case When` statement.

Comment: Please start by disclosing your database system and version. Some modern RDBMS have the aggregate `FILTER` clause as defined in SQL:2003. The rest has to work around it with a `CASE` statement or something.

Comment: @YourCommonSense: You removed the one reference to MySQL by removing the tag `mysqli`. That may not be directly applicable, but the edit wasn't helpful. I tagged `mysql` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case you can do it more simple.

```
SELECT SUM(distance)
FROM your_table
WHERE user = 'X'
```

`SUM(CASE WHEN..)` work for your case too and lot of other even more complicated cases when need more flexibility.

ex:

```
SUM( CASE 
       WHEN user = 'X' THEN distance*2
       WHEN user = 'Y' THEN distance*3
       WHEN user = 'Z' THEN distance/2
       ELSE distance
    END)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when user = 'X' then distance else 0 end) 
from your_table
```